# mysql query for getting corresponding values of similar rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with contents as follows:

```
A        B
chap1   c1
chap1   c2
chap1   c3
```

I want to get all the result.i.e in the select dropdown I am having chap1 as 3 options.For each selected option I have to get the corresponding c1/c2/c3 values. Any help will be appriciable.Thanks in advance.

Comment: show what you have did yet.

Comment: similar questions can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526914/how-can-i-populate-a-dropdown-list-by-selecting-the-value-from-another-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Mysql query will be

```
 SELECT B FORM `table` WHERE A = 'chap1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function group concat:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b)
FROM `table`
```

Here's a [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to the function.