# Dropdown list number must correspond to what room is selected [PHP / MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I have a "room type" dropdown list for the guest to choose what room he / she likes, like this:

[image]

It is inside a "rooms" table in the database.

The goal is when I click an "Ordinary" room, the dropdown box below must correspond to how many I entered in the NumberOfRooms column of that room I entered in the database. Hence, I selected the "NumberOfRooms" column in the database, called it, and put it in the `<options>` value.

Instead I got like this:

[image]

Apparently I got the whole data of "NumberOfRooms" column. It must correspond to whatever I clicked in the Room / Hall type, and the number of rooms should match to that.

Here is my present code:

```
<div class="item form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Room /Hall Type<span style= " color: red" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <select  name="RoomType" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="RoomType">
      <?php
      include 'login/checkdbConnection.php';
      $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM rooms");
      $room_numbers = $r['NumberOfRooms']; 
      while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<option value="'.$result["RoomType"].'">₱'.$result["RoomRate"].' - '.$result["RoomType"].'</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Number of Room<span style= " color: red" class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-5">
    <select  name="NumberOfRooms" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="NumberOfRooms">
      <?php 
      include 'login/checkdbConnection.php';
      $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM rooms");
      while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<option value="'.$result["NumberOfRooms"].'">'.$result["NumberOfRooms"].'</option>';
      }              
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much! =)

Comment: You have to use ajax for it

Comment: I see. how exactly should I use it? Please help, I am so confused.. =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953085/how-can-i-populate-a-dropdown-list-by-selecting-the-value-from-another-dropdown

Comment: check the above link

Comment: You shouldn't have to use ajax- although it can improve end-user experience